# Duda al obtener el mayor valor con la función first value en MySql 10.3.8

Tags: mysql

Debo realizar una consulta sobre la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La observación puede tener varios significados, de allí que existan 4 columnas de acuerdo al tipo de éste. En teoría, de acuerdo al identificador de la observation puedo determinar cual es la columna que debo consultar. Al final el resultado deseado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se busca es obtener es el último valor para cada observación de acuerdo a la actividad que tiene el identificador mayor. Por ejemplo, para la observación 10 el valor correspondiente es el asociado a la actividad 19.

Para ello he implementado el siguiente query:

```
select 
first_value(text) over (partition by employee order by case when observation = 10 then activity else 0 end desc) as "Obs 10",
first_value(number) over (partition by employee order by case when observation = 20 then activity else 0 end desc) as "Obs 20",
first_value(dropdown) over (partition by employee order by case when observation = 40 then activity else 0 end desc) as "Obs 40"
-- the same for the rest of the observations
from employee_proc
```

Estaría funcionando bien. Sin embargo, la lógica contempla que el empleado puede tener asociadas varias observaciones que podrían no haberse generado al momento de realizar la consulta. Es allí donde estoy teniendo problemas, si en el select agrego la clausula

```
...
first_value(text) over (partition by employee order by case when observation = 120 then activity else 0 end desc) as "Obs 120",
...
```

Dado que esta observación aún no se ha registrado, estoy obteniendo resultados erróneos en lugar de NULL, que es lo que me esperaba. Cómo puedo solucionar este inconveniente?

Habría otra manera más óptima de alcanzar el resultado buscado?

Saludos